# Continuity of the function $\begin{cases} \frac{x^3 y^3}{x^3+y^3}, \ \text{if} \ x+y \ne 0, \\ 0, \ \text{if} \ x+y=0 \end{cases}$

Tags: limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Study the continuity of
$$\begin{cases} \frac{x^3 y^3}{x^3+y^3}, \ \text{if} \ x+y \ne 0, \\ 0, \ \text{if} \ x+y=0 \end{cases}$$
$f$ is continuous for all $x+y \ne 0$ because it is a ratio of continuous function and the denominator is non zero if $x+y\ne0$, so the only points I must check with the definition are the ones such that $x+y=0 \iff y=-x$.

So let $a \in \mathbb{R}$, I must check if it is true or false that
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,-a)} f(x,y)=0$$
My attempt: let $s:=x-a$ and $t:= y+a$, then $x=s+a$ and $y=t-a$; so I have to study $g(s,t)=f(s-a,t+a)$ for $(s,t) \to (0,0)$, meaning
$$\lim_{(s,t)\to (0,0)} \frac{(s+a)^3(t-a)^3}{(s+a)^3+(t-a)^3}$$
But this limit doesn't exist, since
$$\lim_{s \to 0} g(s,0)=\lim_{s \to 0} \frac{-a^3 (s^3+3s^3a+3sa^2+a^3)}{s^3+3s^3a+3sa^2+a^3-a^3}$$
$$=\lim_{s \to 0} \frac{-a^3 (s^3+3s^3a+3sa^2+a^3)}{s(s^2+3sa+3a^2)}=\begin{cases} -\infty, \ \text{if} \ s \to 0^+ \\ \infty, \ \text{if} \ s \to 0^-\end{cases}$$
So in particular the limit isn't $0$ and so $g$ is not continuous in the point $(0,0)$, so $f$ is not continuous on the point $(a,-a)$; since $a \in \mathbb{R}$ was arbitrary, $f$ is not continuous in $(a,-a)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.
However my lecturer doesn't use the substitution and he discuss the two separate cases when $a \ne 0$ and $a=0$, so I'm not sure if my approach is correct because maybe I'm missing something when $a=0$ or I should substitute the new variables in the set of definition of $f$ as well. Can someone tell me if my approach is correct and it is equivalent to discuss the two cases $a=0$ and $a \ne 0$? Thanks.

Comment: The last limit calculation seems wrong. The limit $$\lim_{(s,t)\to (0,0)} \; \frac{(s+a)^3(t-a)^3}{(s+a)^3+(t-a)^3}$$ should be directly calculable unless $a = 0$, so that's why your instructor tells you to separate the cases.

Comment: I think it is an (inconsequential) typo that you have "$2sa^2$" terms that should be "$3sa^2$".

Comment: @macton: Ok, can I save my work by saying this: for $a \ne 0$ the limit doesn't exist for the calculation I've done in the question, if $a=0$ then I must evaluate $\lim_{(s,t) \to (0,0)} \frac{s^3 t^3}{s^3+t^3}$ and this limit doesn't exist as well since for $(s,0)$ its value is $0$ while for $(s,-s+s^4)$ it is $-\frac{1}{3}$. What do you think?

Comment: @alex.jordan: Yes, you are right. Thanks for noticing it!

Comment: Yes you are correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed when $a=0$ you have that
$$
\lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \frac{-a^3(s^3+3s^2a+3sa^2+a^3)}{s(s^2+2sa+3a^2)}
$$

turns into:

$$
\lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \frac{-0³(s^3+3s^2(0)+3s\left(0^2\right)+0^3)}{s(s^2+2s(0)+3\left(0^2\right))} = \lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \frac{0}{s(s^2)} = 0
$$

And no contradiction arises from this calculation

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to see which values of $a$ can be problematic or I just have to check them by eye?

Comment: You could look for what are the values of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that your reasoning breaks down, thats how one can spot the a=0 case and, by doing that, one can see that that is the only problematic value.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of $u=\tfrac{x+y}{2}$ and $v=\tfrac{x-y}{2}$, $x=u+v$ and $y=u-v$, so for $u\ne0$ the function is $\tfrac{(u^2-v^2)^3}{2u(u^2+3v^2)}$, which is asymptotic to $\tfrac{-v^4}{6u}$ if $u\ll v$. So we do not have continuity at $u=0$.